# What if I just commit and do not push on Git?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am still curious and do not know how Git works. And I was wondering what if I just committed my files and did not push them.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to answer this if you don't understand what it means for Git to be a *distributed* version-control system. I highly recommend reading [*Pro Git*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), especially the [first section](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control).

Comment: The simple answer is that if you don't push, then you just aren't sharing your commits with a particular remote repository. Git, *by design*, does not require your repository to stay in sync with any other repository, and it's your responsibility to perform this synchronization if you want to share your work with others.

Comment: By the way, note a theme here to the answers: it's all about *commits*. Git itself is really all about commits. It's not about files (though commits hold files), nor is it about branches (though we organize commits into those and use branch *names* to find the commits). In the end it's all about the *commits*. The distributed nature of Git is done by sending and receiving commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case where you commit, but do not `git push` the commit anywhere, that means that only you have that commit.

That's not *the* right thing to do, nor is it *the* wrong thing to do.  It is merely *a thing you can do*.  You can keep all your commits to yourself as much as you like.  If you don't want anyone else to have them, don't send them to anyone else.

If you *do* want someone else to have access to your commits, though, *then* you'll want to send them off, probably with `git push`.